# Share IP address between docker containers

Tags: docker

I am running single node zookeeper docker image using below command
`docker run -it -p 2181:2181 --name zookeeper zookeeper`.
 Inorder to run kafka docker image, I need to share the IP address of the zookeper docker image as ENV variable and update kafka server.properties file.

Using docker inspect, I am able to fetch the IP address of zookeeper image and pass it during `docker run` of kafka.

But is there any way to automatically detect and share the IP address between docker containers.

I could see some example using --link, but in the latest docker documentation it seems deprecated.

Appreciate any suggestion/help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is a perfect solution for your case.

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
>   container for a service joins the default network and is both
>   reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
>   them at a hostname identical to the container name.

The `docker-compose.yaml` is something like below one for your case:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: <zookeeper_image_name>
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
  kafka:
    image: <kafka_image_name>
    restart: always
```

Kafka container should have `zookeeper` as a zookeeper hostname in `server.properties` file.